# Running Boot2Docker on windows, can't connect to the VM ip

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I can't make Docker run the Hello-world or any of server-connection things, as you can see it gives me the client version but at the time of giving me the server version it just can't connect...

I have boot2docker 1.7.0 and running on Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your Boot2Docker VM is not running. The `docker` command tries to connect to the Boot2Docker VM through this IP and port, and it looks like it can't access this IP/port combination. I get a similar error (although not in Spanish) when I try to run `docker version` without starting Boot2Docker first.

Can you go through the steps listed in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/) again:

> 3. Run the **Boot2Docker Start** shortcut from your Desktop or “Program Files → Boot2Docker for Windows”. The Start script will ask you to enter an ssh key passphrase - the simplest (but least secure) is to just hit [Enter].

When doing this, do you see the environment variables printed like in the following screenshot?

[image: Boot2Docker for Windows]

Do you see these variables, or do you see any error messages instead?

Comment: I dont get any error message before running a command, as you can see here: http://prntscr.com/7ryq3n ! I dont know where the script ask me for a key passphrase... Thanks for helping me!